# How to reproduce grep's --recursive option in an old version of grep

Tags: linux, grep

I am working on an ancient UNIX whose `grep` lacks the -r/--recursive option.

I need to find an error that our application is causing, but I do not know which log file our application is writing errors to. However, I do know that the log file is somewhere in `/opt`. So I want to find FooErrorMessage under `/opt` in `*.log`. Here's what I tried:

```
find /opt | xargs grep FooErrorMessage
```

-- but this does not work, and I don't know where to specify that I just want `*.log` files in the command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just trying to find all log files under `/opt` and search them for `somethnig_I_am_looking_for` right?  Why not:

`find /opt -name '*.log' | xargs grep something`

or

`find /opt | grep .log | xargs grep something`

?

Oh, and since I can't figure out how to comment on the other answers: be careful with *.log as the shell will interpret that as globbing, and match all files in the current directory that end in `.log` .  You should use either \*.log or '*.log'

Comment: `\\*.log` or `"*.log"`

Comment: dotjoe - be careful with double-quotes.  The shell interprets stuff inside double quotes.  Single quotes prevent interpretation.

Answer (score 4):

Beware of filenames with spaces in them, as it is allowed by Unix; xargs will choke on them. Use `find /opt -name '*.log' ... -print0 | xargs -0 grep ...`, these options are meant to go together.

Also, grep or your shell might have a limited number of arguments, and the list of files returned by find might exceed that. Use the `-n number` option of xargs to run grep by chunks of *number* files.

Comment: +1 for '`find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...`'.  The operating system will limit the total length of the arguments (and the size of the environment also comes out of the same space - so lots of environment variables reduces the number of arguments you can use), but `xargs` should be attuned to the o/s limit and not create overlong argument lists.  Certainly, I don't recall that being a problem ever.

Answer (score 3):

do you have perl?

try -- http://betterthangrep.com/

Comment: I use Ack every day. I especially like the smart-casing option.

Answer (score 1):

`find /opt -type f -name *.log -print | xargs grep 'something_I_am_looking_for'`

Comment: You need quotes around '`*.log`' to be safe.  (And, as written, you do not need quotes around '`something_I_am_looking_for`', but it is likely better to include them than omit them - certainly in general.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from adding the "-name '*.log'", try adding -n1 to xargs.

Maybe your ancient grep can't take multiple input files, so -n1 will run grep for each of those files, instead of passing them as arguments at once

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with the exec option to find instead of xargs

> find /opt -exec grep "thing you are looking for" {} \;

Comment: That launches a command for each file found - that gets expensive by comparison with using `xargs`.

Answer (score 1):

GNU grep has its own “recurse” option:

```
 grep -R foo /path/to/directory
```

To grep files of a particular pattern, you’re best off with `find` and `xargs`:

```
 find /path/to/directory -name \*.log -print0 | xargs -0 grep foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find /opt -name *.log | xargs grep yourstring
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have subdirectories that are many levels deep, grep *, grep */* and grep */*/* is easy to remember and hard to type wrong...